# Laravel 8 Undefined varible posts

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have an error.. it says:

Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\dinsospermasdes\bansus\resources\views\admin\posts\index.blade.php)

it works in home.blade.php like this:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{‌{filter_var($post->post_image, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? $post->post_image : '/storage/' . $post->post_image}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">{‌{$post->title}}</h2>
        <p class="card-text">{‌{Str::limit($post->body, '50', '....')}}</p>
        <a href="{‌{route('post', $post->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        Posted on {‌{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}} by
        <a href="#">{‌{$post->name}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

but didn't work in admin/posts/index.blade.php like this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
                      <tr>
                          <td>{‌{$post->id}}</td>
                          <td>{‌{$post->title}}</td>
                          <td>
                            <img height="40px" src="{‌{filter_var($post->post_image, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? $post->post_image : '/storage/' . $post->post_image}}">
                          </td>
                          <td>{‌{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                          <td>{‌{$post->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
```

this is PostController.php:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function index(){
        $post = Post::all();
        return view('admin.posts.index');
    }

    public function show(Post $post){
        return view ('blog-post', ['post'=>$post]);
    }

    public function create(){
        return view ('admin.posts.create');
    }

    public function store(){
        $inputs = request()->validate([
            'title'=>'required|min:8|max:255',
            'post_image'=>'file', //mime: jpeg, png
            'body'=>'required'
        ]);
        if(request('post_image')){
            $inputs['post_image'] = request('post_image')->store('images');
        }
        auth()->user()->posts()->create($inputs);
        return back();
    }
}
```

this is routes from web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/post/{post}', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'show'])->name('post');    

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.index');

    Route::get('/admin/posts', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'index'])->name('post.index');
    Route::get('/admin/posts/create', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'create'])->name('post.create');
    Route::post('/admin/posts', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'store'])->name('post.store');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In index method you need to pass `posts`

```
public function index(){
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('admin.posts.index',compact('posts'));
}
```

you're not passing `posts variable` in blade file. Hence, it is giving you `undefined error`.

Comment: Can you show me the url in browser?? which route are you getting this error?

Comment: url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/posts

and it seems error from code:
`@foreach($posts as post)`

in C:\xampp\htdocs\dinsospermasdes\bansus\resources\views\admin\posts\index.blade.php)

Comment: after `compact('posts')` it must be working. can dd in blade file.

Comment: oh wait.. it has following error like this:
compact(): Undefined variable: posts....

Comment: Did you change `$post = Post::all();` to `$posts = Post::all();`???

Comment: aisshh... i forgot that i'm using `$post = Post::all()` not `$posts = Post::all()`... and the correct answer  is using `$posts`... thanks for your help :)

Comment: oh! Finally, you got the solution. :)